# Disable tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, tabs

In recent versions of Ubuntu and particularly the upcoming 14.04LTS, I find that I prefer to not use tabs in Firefox, but rather use the app spread. So that's what I do. However, I haven't found a way to remove the tab bar from Firefox and it seems kind of pointless for every one-page window to have a tab bar containing only one tab. Sometimes, it also fools me into using the new-tab button from old habit, so it would really be quite useful to be able to remove that bar altogether.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this add-on to hide the tab bar if there's only one tab in a window: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/hide-tab-bar-with-one-tab/

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do so by making a stylesheet yourself:

Create or modify `/home/your_name/.mozilla/firefox/profile_name/extensions/chrome/userChrome.css`. Paste these lines if you create the file:

```
@namespace xul url(http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul);
#TabsToolbar { display: none !important }
```

Only add

```
#TabsToolbar { display: none !important }
```

if you already have functional `userChrome.css` with first line already present.

Notes:

- Firefox is going to bring big changes with Australis (v29 in April 2014?). Some UI elements will be locked in place.
- I have tested this code in Australis and not in current Firefox because I use Australis.
- I think you should be able to use the same code in Firefox 27.

Image before:

[image: Before]

Image after:

[image: After]

Comment: That's a bad idea, since it completely prevents interfacing with the tab bar. It's better to use an add-on for this, so the tab bar still shows if for example a website gets accidentally opened in a background tab instead of a new window.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add to DK Bose's answer. You better use this

```
#TabsToolbar {height: 0 !important }
```

because if you turn off the display you are going to have problems with addons for sure. For example, Firegestures starts to throw errors at you if you try to manage tabs with it.